# Unable To Install Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, subprocess

pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [10 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-65.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from their docs

Kivy 2.1.0 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.10.

you are using 3.11.  Try using python 3.10

(although from your prints it looks like they are in the process of supporting 3.11 (since it could install other kivy specific requirements for 3.11))

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your insight

Comment: I was able to install kivy using the 'developer method' from the documentation today and  python 3.11 nominally works on my Windows machine.  ideally though a person would wait for formal support.